# Python TCP/IP client in NAO robot

Tags: python, image, sockets, tcp, nao-robot

today I tried to make a TCP/IP client in NAO robot. I use server made in C# and it works good(tried it many times). My task is to make TCP/IP client in python which can send an Image(jpg) and nothing else. To describe a problem I can give you an example. I am making photo using NAOs camera and I want to send this image using TCP/IP protocol. I used many "tactics" but with no working output. I tried this code:

```
import socket
sckt = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sckt.connect(("192.168.0.106",5000)) #server IP and port
fname = "image.jpg"
fileDir = "/home/nao/recordings/cameras/"
fname = fileDir + fname
nf = open(fname,'w')
nf.write(strng)
nf.close()
sckt.send(nf)
sckt.close()
```

After running this code, socket on NAOs side just doesn't close and I have no idea why. And I still can't send an image.
Can you guys help me with this task?

BTW I am a novice in python

THX VM :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that because you need these following steps, of cause this is one option on the client side for your case:

1. open the file and read it in buffer
2. send it
3. close the socket
4. close the file

   ```
   import socket
   sckt = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
   sckt.connect(("192.168.0.106",5000)) #server IP and port
   fname = "image.jpg"
   fileDir = "/home/nao/recordings/cameras/"
   fname = fileDir + fname
   nf = open(fname,'r') # r-->rw if you want
   sckt.send(nf)
   sckt.close()
   nf.close()
   ```

Comment: Hi,This is really a nice answer. I am also facing the same situation where i need to read an image file from Nao or download the same file to my local python directory. Can you please help me on how to download image file from Nao to local directory, using this Socket.
I am new to Nao and Python too. 
Thanks for the help